# trying to create route of blade file

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to jump on details.blade.php page but getting error

> Route [admin.leads.details] not defined. (View:
> C:\Users\810te\lms\resources\views\admin\leads\index.blade.php)

here is my code:

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('leads', LeadsController::class)->except([
    'destroy'
]);
Route::resource('leads/{id}/details','LeadsController@details');
```

**LeadsController.php**

```
public function details(Lead $lead)
{       
    return view('admin.leads.details');
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<a href="{{route('admin.leads.details',$lead->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning p-0"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

after click button i want to jump on details.blade.php.that i have created on same path of `index.blade.php` file

Comment: Could you paste the output of `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: `admin.leads.details` is the name of the blade view, not the route. Since your route isn't named, use the actual URL instead, or name the route.